# MSBuild: (WebDeploy) Web package creation for selected web projects

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I managed to get TFS 2010 to create Web Deployment ZIPs (WebDeploy).

Now the issue is that I have multiple Web projects in the solution and packages are being created for all web projects.

In the projects that I do not want a package, I uncheck the "Create deployment package as a zip". I thought this will prevent MSBuild from creating a deployment package.

BTW I am passing "/p:DeployOnBuild=true" to MSBuild.

Is there a way to get MSBuild only package selected projects and not all Web projects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Found the solution. Many thanks to Vishal Joshi for this [post](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html).

Extract from the post:

---

"
Deployment for Web Apps is feasible at both Solution as well as Project build level although when it comes to Solution Build then you might want to make sure that the properties you are passing at Solution level will apply to all the projects in the solution which might not always the outcome you desire. In that situation all these properties can be set within the .csproj or .vbproj files too. You can do that by unloading your project file and in the top `<PropertyGroup>` section just add above properties as you like:

For e.g `/p:DeployOnBuild=True` can be added as `<DeployOnBuild>True</DeployOnBuild>`
"

---

So, the solution was to remove `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` from TFS Build process template and update only the project files that require a package.